# Dynamics 365 link attachment to email after moving it to Sharepoint on-prem using Onpremise data gateway

Tags: sharepoint-2013, dynamics-365, power-automate

In Dynamics 365 Customer engagement module, I have created a flow to create the attachments of existing email activities to Sharepoint 2013 on-prem, using Onpremise data gateway.

[D365 Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2qCK.png)

[Email Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34NOX.png)

Now I want to update Email activities(in the above screen), to point to sharepoint attachment location.

How we can achieve this using Microsoft flow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there,

You have your document moved/created in Sharepoint.

now create one more flow or extend same flow, when file is created in SharePoint,
Then you need to [create document location records in CRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-edit-document-location-records). This record will hold details about location of your sharepoint and it's file as relative url and regarding to your Email record.

Before you create or extend your flow, try to create sharepoint document location record per hand with adding all the info required such as relative url or absolute url and so on.

Then check if you can see the document in your email record. If you do then you can move to power automate to automate the same.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In order to link the document to entity, is it important that sharepoint on-premise site should be accessible over internet or we can access using Onpremise data gateway.